# Get application directory using C# Console Application?

Tags: c#, console, directory

I found something on google but it not working on C# Console Application

What I found:

```
string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

How I can get application directory using c# Console Application?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you still want to use Application.ExecutablePath in console application you need to:

1. Add a reference to System.Windows.Forms namespace
2. Add System.Windows.Forms to your usings section

   ```
   using System;
   using System.IO;
   using System.Windows.Forms;

   namespace ConsoleApplication1
   {
       class Program
       {
           static void Main(string[] args)
           {
               string appDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
               Console.WriteLine(appDirectory);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Also you can use [`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx) instead of `Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)` and thus you won't need a reference to System.Windows.Forms.

If you'd like not to include neither `System.IO` nor `System.Windows.Forms` namespaces then you should follow Reimeus's answer.

Comment: -1 because `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` gets the current working directory rather than the directory containing the application.

Comment: @Sam but I still prefer that. I don't want to depend on Forms.

Answer (score 15):

Application is not available for Console Applications, it's for windows forms.

To get the working directory you can use

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

Also to get the directory of the executable, you could use:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Answer (score 9):

BEWARE, there are several methods and PITFALLS for paths.

- What location are you after? The working directory, the .EXE directory, the DLLs directory?
- Do you want code that also works in a service or console application?
- Will your code break if the directory has inconsistent trailing slashes?

Lets look at some options:

```
Application.ExecutablePath
```

Requires adding a reference and loading the Application namespace.

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory
Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

If the program is run by shortcut, registry, task manager, these will give the 'Start In' folder, which can be different from the .EXE location.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Depending on how it's run effects whether it includes a trailing slash. This can break things, for example GetDirectoryName() considers no slash to be a file, and will remove the last part.

Either of these are my recommendation, working in both Form and Console applications:

```
var AssemblyPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
or
var AssemblyPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

When used in a main program, both are indentical. If used within a DLL, the first returns the .EXE directory that loaded the DLL, the second returns the DLLs directory.

Comment: -1 `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory May or may not have a trailing slash depending on how the application is launched` What about `Path.Combine`? Didn't you listen about it before?

Comment: @Kilanny Why the downvote? Yes Path.Combine takes care of slashes, but what if you are not joining paths? For example passing the directory to a command line program where slashes can change the behaviour.

Comment: Let `Path.Combine` aside, Why didn't you invoke `Path.GetDirectoryName` onto `BaseDIrectory` also as you did on `Assembly.Location`?

Comment: @Desolator sorry for late reply.  Because of the inconsistent trailing slash, BaseDirectory may be treated as a file path by GetDirectoryName() which causes it to remove the last part of the path.  I've updated my answer to be clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Try [`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx)

Comment: -1 because `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` gets the current working directory rather than the directory containing the application.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a long long time, but `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase` worked for me. You just have to replace `Application.ExecutablePath` with it.

Of course you have to add `using System.Reflection;`

I have tried using `System.Windows.Forms` but it gave me an exception